# Is it a good practice to modify global variables inside a function by passing it using pointers?

Tags: c

```
globals.h
unsigned char csrf;
unsigned char srevf;
pcs.c
void PcsTxFlags(unsigned char*pCsrf, unsigned char*psrevf,
                 unsigned char penablef0,unsigned char penablef2, 
                 unsigned char penablef4)
    {
       *pcsrf =penablef2 & (penablef0 ? 0:1);
       *psrevf = penablef2 ^ penablef4;
    }
main.c
int main(void)
 {
   PcsTxFlags(&csrf,&srevf,penablef0 ,penablef2 ,penablef4);
}
```

I get the correct results. It is known that there is no need to pass a global variable and it can be modified inside a function without passing it. So is it a good practice to modify the global variable inside the function by passing it as an argument using pointers.

Comment: it is bad practice to have global state, no matter how you modify it

Comment: Depends, is there any chance you'll want to make these variables **not** global later?

Comment: It also presupposes the question "Why would you worry about passing a global at all?" If it's global, you don't need to pass it to update it, if you do pass a variable by the same name, you risk **shadowing** the global and not updating the global at all. That is a primary reason you want to avoid globals to begin with (and also compile with the `-Wshadow` option)

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not a thing that is used too frequently to become a practice. Global variables is being modified - no matter what you are scattering the points where a variable can be modified, all drawbacks of it will come with this.(Hard to manage code, tracing a bug etc).

Then also I would say, that based on scenario and the functionality achieved in the function - passing by pointer leave the scope of reusing the function. If you used global var directly then there will be little scope of using it (the function) again. This is sometimes needed - for example you are using a library for `xml` parsing. Even if you have the data structure placed globally, you have to modify it by calling the api's provided.(Passing a global variable's address).

And also it is bad practice to have too many global variables for achieving a seemingly trivial work. Now this trivial work is subjective and contextual.